# PostgreSQL funcion max return numeric from decimal

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need dicimal type with some precision like `decimal(12,2)`, but when i use max function they return `numeric` type without precision. Why they transform type and how save precision when i use max?

```
select max(12.2::decimal(12,2))
```

return

12.2 as numeric

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result of the max aggregate, not the input:

```
max(...)::numeric(12,2)
```